# MS Excel: Pivot Worksheet(s) Refresh vs Refresh All

Tags: excel, pivot, refresh

I have a project where neither Open Office nor Star Office would open the client's xlsx.  It is 125 MB with many macros and worksheets with pivot tables.

I see that refreshing causes the pivot to update based on the data I've pasted into the data worksheet, but what is the difference between "Refresh" and "Refresh All"?

My gut tells me that "Refresh" refreshes the pivot from the new data on the current worksheet, and "Refresh All" refresh the pivots on all worksheets found in the xlsx file.

[image]

> Please clarify this and include how I can refresh all worksheets at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the information to match the data source, click the Refresh button.

To refresh all PivotTables in the workbook, click the Refresh button arrow, and then click Refresh All (as in your screenshot).

Here us the site I used to verify this: [Refresh Pivot Table @ support.office.com](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Refresh-PivotTable-data-6d24cece-a038-468a-8176-8b6568ca9be2)

[image]